# Clipboard sharing between different users in MacOS X

Tags: macos, clipboard, skype

How can I share the clipboard between three skype instances, started by three different users, on a MacOS X machine?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a programming question or a Skype user question?  I don't think Skype is open source, so how could this be a programming question?

The clipboard is not owned by any particular app on OSX.  If one instance of Skype puts something on the clipboard, the other instances should see it.  So it seems like you are asking "why don't the other apps see it" or in other words, "is there a bug in Skype", which we can't answer if we can't see the code.